# Problems in Embed PDF content

Tags: c#, html, pdf, blazor, embed

This works very well when the files are small. As soon as the files get larger (> 1 MB). Can no longer display the PDF.

```
<embed src="@PDFContent" style="width: 100%;height: 930px;border: none;" frameborder="0" />
```

```
PDFContent = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"Server:\Temp\test.pdf"));
```

The file is on a server and not on the IISS.
what could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<embed>`, try using `<iframe>`.
Moreover, convert your **base64** data back to binary, packed in a **Blob** and then set your iframe's src to a blob-URI pointing to that Blob -

```
const blob = base64ToBlob( base64, 'application/pdf' );
const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
const pdfWindow = window.open("");
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + url + "'></iframe>");

function base64ToBlob( base64, type = "application/octet-stream" ) {
  const binStr = atob( base64 );
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[ i ] = binStr.charCodeAt( i );
  }
  return new Blob( [ arr ], { type: type } );
}
```

If this approach doesn't work out, try to make your `<iframe>` point directly to the PDF's URL.

Hope this solution works out for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works great.
Is there also a possibility to integrate the iframe into an existing page? I don't want to have a separate window.
I've tried the innerHTML of a div, but without success.

Comment: I'm glad that my solution could be of some help to you. Please consider accepting my Answer as others who might face this problem could make use of it too.

Comment: About using <iframe> in an existing page, try implementing it using inline frames, you can find the resources easily online.